# Boost Graph CRS: bulk weights and Dijkstra

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am trying to construct a graph as efficiently as possible, and since I don't need to change my graph at runtime, I've opted for a `boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph`. Now the question is simple: how can I add weights to edges and call `boost::dijkstra_shortest_paths`?

So far I've accomplished to create a graph, but I don't know how to proceed.

My requirements are: waste as little memory and time as possible. I'm facing graphs with a number of nodes potentially reaching 10^6. I am following this [wiki](http://programmingexamples.net/wiki/CPP/Boost/BGL/DijkstraComputePath) entry, but I'm afraid that property maps, index maps & Co., as I see in the wiki, will be an additional burden to my program.

Do you think is there a way of minimizing the memory footprint?

Thanks for your help!

```
// Properties: weights
typedef boost::property<boost::edge_weight_t, int> edge_weight;

// The graph itself as a compressed sparse row matrix
typedef boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph<boost::bidirectionalS, boost::no_property, edge_weight> boost_graph;

// Vertex iterator
typedef boost::graph_traits<boost_graph>::vertex_iterator vertex_iterator;

// Edge iterator
typedef boost::graph_traits<boost_graph>::edge_iterator edge_iterator;

// Adjacent nodes iterator
typedef boost::graph_traits<boost_graph>::adjacency_iterator adjacency_iterator;
typedef boost::graph_traits<boost_graph>::out_edge_iterator  outward_iterator;
typedef boost::graph_traits<boost_graph>::in_edge_iterator   inward_iterator;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>> graph_edges;
    std::vector<int>                                 edge_weight;

    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 0,  1)); edge_weight.push_back(1);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 0,  3)); edge_weight.push_back(2);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 1,  4)); edge_weight.push_back(2);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 2,  4)); edge_weight.push_back(3);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 3,  4)); edge_weight.push_back(1);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 4,  5)); edge_weight.push_back(1);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 4,  6)); edge_weight.push_back(5);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 5,  7)); edge_weight.push_back(4);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 7,  8)); edge_weight.push_back(1);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 8,  9)); edge_weight.push_back(3);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 8, 11)); edge_weight.push_back(2);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 8, 12)); edge_weight.push_back(3);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair( 9, 10)); edge_weight.push_back(2);
    graph_edges.push_back(std::make_pair(12, 10)); edge_weight.push_back(4);

    // Create the graph
    boost_graph graph(boost::edges_are_unsorted_multi_pass, graph_edges.begin(), graph_edges.end(), 13);
    // ...

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a graph in bulk is possible with contiguous containers such as `std::vector`:

```
    boost_graph graph(boost::edges_are_unsorted_multi_pass, graph_edges.begin(), graph_edges.end(), edge_weight.data(), 13);
```